# Object 'H2_max' not found when trying to compute H2' for a bipartite network

Tags: r, if-statement, bipartite

I am trying to get a value for `H2` for a plant pollinator network in R. I have a network matrix as follows:
[image]

The numerical values represent visits/flowers to account for differences in flower size and abundance for each plant species.

When I try to find H2' using
`H2fun(intnetwork, H2_integer = FALSE)`
(intnetwork being my network matrix), I get this error every time: `Error in ifelse(H2_max >= H2_max.improved, H2_max, H2_max.improved) :  object 'H2_max' not found`
Have tried so many things to try and fix it to no avail.
Please help!

Answer (score 0):

It seems the package had a bug. The problem was solved but the new version of the package was not yet resubmitted to CRAN: https://github.com/biometry/bipartite/issues/13.

Just run this and the problem should be solved:

```
library(devtools)
install_github("biometry/bipartite/bipartite")
```